# GetJSON for crossdomain request

Tags: javascript, json, jquery

I'm trying to collect some data from an opendata service. i'm stuck with my jquery request,
folowing the example from [Jquery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) which use the flicker API, it works. But when I changed the URL, I don't get the callback action played (here an alert popup). I can see in the Chrome console that the request is played and the correct result returns, but no action is performed in my callback.

Here is my test :

```
     <html>
     <body>
     <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
     <span id="info"></span>
     <script>  
       $.getJSON("https://open.tan.fr/ewp/tempsattente.json/SECH?jsoncallback=?",
       {},
     function(data) {
              alert("foo");
     });
     </script>
     </body>
     </html>
```

Can someone tell me why it don't to works? any suggestion ?
Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that https://open.tan.fr/ewp/tempsattente.json/SECH supports JSONP and that the callback parameter name is `jsoncallback`?

Comment: check cross domain issus (origin source policy).

Comment: Try chaining `.error(function () { alert("error"); });` to the end and see if that fires - http://jsfiddle.net/dCTES/

Comment: I get "Error: jQuery18206930075496322584_1355933072137 was not called" because of a `parsererror`

Comment: It has an unexpected error: it encounters a weird character - `"Fran\u00e7ois Mitterrand"`: http://jsfiddle.net/dCTES/1/

Comment: The server needs to support JSONP.  If it doesn't, then you can't access it like that.  You can use a server-side proxy, in that case.

Comment: @RocketHazmat The OP already said they get the right response back (by looking at the Chrome console), so it has nothing to do with JSONP support...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `.error` on the `getJSON` method, you can find out why it failed (hopefully). Since you said you seem to be getting the correct response and it "works", it makes sense that it's a parsing error (basically all that's left after a `200` is received). If you use `.error`, you find this message:

```
Error: jQuery18206930075496322584_1355933072137 was not called
```

and in a different place, find it was because of a

```
parsererror
```

^ http://jsfiddle.net/dCTES/

If you take the actual response and run it through `JSON.parse`, it says:

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character
```

And it is pointing to the value:

```
"Fran\u00e7ois Mitterrand"
```

^ http://jsfiddle.net/dCTES/1/

Comment: thank you for the hand ! Yes I get those unexpected character... there is any way to manage those unexpected characters with query?